# How to implement "ls a*" in Nodejs to list specific files in a directory (readdir lists all)?

Tags: node.js

I have a directory in which there are many files and I want to pick only one file that I know starts with a certain prefix and thats it. One easy way to find if such a file exists is to use [readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) or [readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) to get an array with names of all files and then check if one of them starts with the string I have.

That I think is inefficient because of the number of files in the directory. Is there a better way to accomplish this and particularly so because there is only one file in the folder whose prefix will match the one I specify.

Comment: You're probably seeking this: [glob-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-all)

Comment: @mtsdev I found a simple solution of using the child_process module to execute "ls" and then parse the result. This way I can pass any shell regular expression pattern to filter the files. Did take a look at glob-all. Would have worked too but I think my solution does not require me to install any external module. Yes, glob-all has other features which could come in handy. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre Probably seeking something like this: [glob-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-all)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try

- [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/) which base on [vinyl-fs](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs) and [Glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob).
- [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs), which is a portable (Windows/Linux/OS X) implementation of Unix shell commands on top of the Node.js API.